# Upload images to Azure

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, windows-phone

As part of a personal project, I wish I could send a picture from my Windows Phone to stokage Azure.

I can take a picture with my phone but I do not know how to send it on the storage

Can you help me? tutorials, articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find your happiness on Channel9 with this video that explains exactly what you want to do (and in 4 minutes!) ;)

[Using Windows Azure Storage on Windows Phone](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/windowsazure/learn/Using-Windows-Azure-Storage-on-Windows-Phone)